# Importing JSON dictionary to Core Data in Swift

Tags: json, core-data, import, xcode6, xcode6.1

I've run into a bit of trouble importing bools from JSON dictionary into the `Exercises` object below using Swift. The `Stretch` & `Equipment` objects are a snap. I know it's something really easy, but I'm unable to find an example I can model. Here's my data model:
[image]

The `Stretch` object is my main entity.
The `Equipment` object will contain strings.
The `Exercises` object attributes are Bools.

```
    let jsonURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("seed", withExtension: "json")!
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: jsonURL)

    var error: NSError?
    let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: nil, error: &error) as NSArray

    // Inserts attributes for database

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Stretch", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)!

    var counter = 0

    for jsonDictionary in jsonArray {

        counter++
        // listing of columns in JSON seed file
        let stretchDescription = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("stretchDescription") as String
        let generalArea = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("generalArea") as String
        let muscleGroup = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("muscleGroup") as String
        let equipmentCode = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("equipmentCode") as String
        let sideMultiplier = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("sideMultiplier") as NSNumber
        let advanced = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("advanced") as Bool
        let photo = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("photo") as NSData
        let runningOrWalking = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("runningOrWalking") as Bool
        let cycling = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("cycling") as Bool
        let weightLifting = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("weightLifting") as Bool
        let aerobics = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("aerobics") as Bool
        let raquetSports = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("raquestSports") as Bool
        let golf = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("golf") as Bool
        let yoga = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("yoga") as Bool
        let equipmentDescription = jsonDictionary.valueForKey("equipmentDescription") as String

        let stretch = Stretch(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.context)

        stretch.stretchDescription = stretchDescription
        stretch.generalArea = generalArea
        stretch.muscleGroup = muscleGroup
        stretch.equipmentCode = equipmentCode
        stretch.sideMultiplier = sideMultiplier
        stretch.advanced = advanced
        stretch.photo = photo

        // Insert Equipment object
        let equipmentEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Equipment", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
        let equipmentDescriptionObject = Equipment(entity: equipmentEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)

        stretch.equipmentUsed = equipmentDescriptionObject

        // Figure out exercises object
        let exercise = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Exercises", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
        let exerciseObject = Exercises(entity:exercise!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
```

This is where I'm stuck. How would I finish up adding the attributes for the Exercises object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is where I'm stuck. How would I finish up adding the attributes for the Exercises object?

The same way you added attributes to `Stretch` object. You can easily access and set the `Exercise` attributes via dot notation.

```
let exercise = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Exercises", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
let exerciseObject = Exercises(entity:exercise!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
exerciseObject.aerobics = aerobics
```

Comment: Thank you! It's one thing to follow along in a tutorial, but sometimes things that are very simple are more difficult than they should be when I'm involved ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm checking out this lib (Sync) which looks great to convert JSON object to Core Data object :
https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync